# C++ function not declared after DLL linkage with g++ at CentOS7

Tags: c++, dll, g++

I am trying to link a dll with a very simple testing program, but I am getting an error, that I will describe at the end of the post.

**frvt11.h** - Interface (just relevant code) I need to implement to create my dll

```
namespace FRVT {
    class Interface {
    public:
        static std::shared_ptr<Interface>
        getImplementation();
    }
}
```

**implementation.h** - Header of my implementation of Inteface

```
#include "frvt11.h"

namespace FRVT {
    class Implementation : public FRVT::Interface {
    public:
        static std::shared_ptr<Interface>
        getImplementation();
    }
}
```

**implementation.cpp** - My implementation of Interface

**UPDATE:** change from Implementation::getImplementation to Interface::getImplementation

```
#include "implementation.h"
using namespace FRVT;

std::shared_ptr<Interface> 
Interface::getImplementation() {
    std::cout<<"getImplementation";
    return std::make_shared<Implementation>();
}
```

**main.cpp**

**UPDATE:** Explicitly indicate the namespace Interface::

```
#include "frvt11.h"
using namespace FRVT;

int main(){
    auto obj = Interface::getImplementation();
    return 0;
}
```

**compilation directives**

**UPDATE:** include of -L/dll-directory where are all .h, .cpp and dll

```
g++ -std=c++11 -c -Wall -Werror -m64 -fPIC implementation.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -shared -m64 -o libimplementation.so implementation.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -m64 -o main main.cpp -L/dll-directory -limplementation
```

**error**

**UPDATE**: Original problem solved

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:6:34: error: 'getImplementation' was not declared in this scope
    auto obj = getImplementation();
```

How to solve this error? I was expecting that the linker would do the "magic" to say to main.cpp, that the implementation of referred function would be at the dll. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `getImplementation` is a templated function with no arguments, so the template type can not be deduced. You need to use `getImplementation<Interface>()`.    Or just not template the function if it always returns a `FRVT::Interface`.

Comment: @RichardCritten the frvt11.h is not mine, so I need to use it as it is. getImplementation should return a managed pointer to the Interface object, and that is why I've implemented it returning a shared pointer of my implementation. Well.. I am just giving more information, because I didn't actually figured out how to solve it. Thank you anyway.

Comment: `main()` calls a namespace-level `getImplementation()`, but I see no namespace-level functions named `getImplementation()` ... am I missing something?

Comment: @StephenM.Webb I was just updating my question and closing it with the solution I've found, when you pointed that, but you were right and it is part of the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At implementation.cpp I've changed from:

```
Implementation::getImplementation()
```

to:

```
Interface::getImplementation()
```

At main.cpp I've explicitly indicate the interface, like bellow:

```
auto obj = Interface::getImplementation();
```

And finally I've used the -L directive to indicate where was the the generated dll.